# Wordpres Error, CentOs server: The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini

Tags: php, wordpress

I've installed the last version of wordpress Centos Server, when tried to install a plugin I got the following error "The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in **php.ini**".

I tried to modify **php.ini** and **wp-config-sample.php** following some tutorials, but I still can't upload something more than 2 MB. Any advice would be welcome.

Comment: did you change the right file? did you restart the server after changing the file? you may also be able to set the value in an .htaccess file (depending on hosting)

Comment: Yes, I did change the right files. What do you mean about restarting the server? I'm working in a virtual machine with Centos Server. I didn't can't find the .htacess :( @smith

Comment: depending on how php is being run, you may have to restart the web-server for the changes to take affect.

Answer (score 1):

you can confirm the status of your php setup using `phpinfo();` more details about this can be found here http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php

There are three places where you could make the change, where you need to apply the change the value depends on where it is set, also you will need to   make sure post_max_size is set the same or higher

.htaccess - https://www.a2hosting.co.uk/kb/developer-corner/php/using-php-directives-in-custom-htaccess-files/setting-the-php-maximum-upload-file-size-in-an-htaccess-file

php.ini - https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/php/increase-the-max-file-upload-size-in-php-ini

you can also try this from within your themes functions.php by using

```
@ini_set( 'upload_max_size' , '64M' );
@ini_set( 'post_max_size', '64M');
```

I hope this helps,

Comment: forgot to mention the php.ini should be in /etc/php.ini